# How to Display the set of series not from the array?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

i have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 7
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 7
)
```

we have to split the array like (order should be `3,4,5,6,7`)

Output should be

```
Array 1: 3,4,5,6,7 (3 is taken from [0],4 is taken from [3],5 is taken from [4],6 is taken from [6],7 is taken from [7])
Array 2: 3,-,-,-,- (3 is taken from [2] nd position)
Array 3: -,-,-,6,7 (6 is taken from [1] nd position,7 is taken from [5] nd position)
```

Comment: thats very arbitrary.  some context would be nice :)  Otherwise, the way you have it.  Why not just store them like you showed...why do you need help?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what youre asking is this...

```
  $array = array(3,6,3,4,5,7,6,7);

  $array1 = array($array[0],$array[3],$array[4],$array[6],$array[7]);
  $array2 = array($array[2],"-","-","-","-");
  $array3 = array("-","-","-",$array[1],$array[5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using loop

```
$arr = array (3,6,3,4,5,7,6,7);
$snewarr =array();
$tnewarr =array();
$i =0;
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
  if($k=='0' || $k=='3' || $k=='4' || $k=='6' || $k=='7') {
    $fnewarr[] = $v;
  }
  if($k=='2') {
    $snewarr[] = $v;
  } 
  if(sizeof($snewarr) > 0 && $i<=5){
    array_push($snewarr, '-');
  }

  if($i<=5){
    if($i<=3){
      array_push($tnewarr, '-');
     }
    if($k=='1' || $k=='5') {
      $tnewarr[] = $v;
    }
 }
  $i++;
}
$tnewarr[4] =  $tnewarr[2];
$tnewarr[2] = '-';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($fnewarr); //Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 [4] => 7 )
print_r($snewarr); //Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => - [2] => - [3] => - [4] => - )
print_r($tnewarr); //Array ( [0] => - [1] => - [2] => - [3] => - [4] => 6 [5] => 7 )
```

or in simple way manually set keys directly like :-

```
 $fnewarr= array($arr[0],$arr[3],$arr[4],$arr[6],$arr[7]);
  $snewarr= array($arr[2],'-','-','-','-');
  $tnewarr= array('-','-','-',$arr[1],$arr[5]);
```

Comment: I actually just tested that in Snadbox, it doesn't work as you'd expect. Which is why I deleted it from my post.  I think he actually wants the dashes in the array.  Though Im not sure

Comment: not only 0 to 7 position, it should be dynamic. any no of array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array   = array(3,6,3,4,5,7,6,7);
sort($array);
print_r($array);
```

seems you are trying to sort by array associative values

hope this would be helpful.